# Return only single record if name is test

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table:

```
Declare @t table (ID int,name nvarchar(100))

Insert into @t values (1,'Test')
Insert into @t values (1,'A')
Insert into @t values (1,'B')
Insert into @t values (2,'R')
Insert into @t values (2,'S')
Insert into @t values (3,'T')
```

My requirement is to return only 1 record for the id which is having 'Test' as name:

My output will return:

```
ID  name
1   Test    
2   R   
2   S   
3   T
```

I tried this query:

```
select * from @t t
where exists (select 1 from @t t1 where t.ID=t1.ID and name ='test')
```

But no luck.

Can anyone please tell me what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM @t t
WHERE t.name = 'Test'
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @t WHERE ID = t.ID AND name = 'Test')
```

Or with `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT ID, name
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Test' THEN name END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) test
  FROM @t
) t
WHERE test IS NULL OR name = test;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6159bb12f0514266ac050af261585ccf).
Results:

```
> ID | name
> -: | :---
>  1 | Test
>  2 | R   
>  2 | S   
>  3 | T
```

Comment: max with partition does the trick for me. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK` as follows:

```
select id,name from 
(select id, name, 
        DENSE_RANK()
          over(partition by id 
               order by case when t.id = 1 then 1 else 2 end) rn
from @t)t
where t.rn = 1
```